# Definition 2.1. Chapter 3 - Do Carmo's Riemannian Geometry

Tags: notation, manifolds, definition

Chapter 3, section 2.

> Definition 2.1. : A parametrized curve $\gamma : I \to M$ is a geodesic at $t_0 \in I$ if $\frac{D}{dt} \left( \frac{d\gamma}{dt}\right) = 0$ at the point $t_0$; if $\gamma$ is a geodesic at $t$, for all $t \in I$, we say that $\gamma$ is a geodesic. If $[a,b] \in I$ and $\gamma : I \to M$ is a geodesic, the restriction of $\gamma$ to $[a,b]$ is called geodesic segment joining $\gamma(a)$ to $\gamma(b)$.

Right after this definition the following expression is given for the arc length

$$
s(t) = \int_{t_0}^t \left| \frac{d \gamma}{dt}\right| dt = c(t - t_0)
$$
with the assumption $c = \left| \frac{d \gamma}{dt}\right|$ is some non zero constant.

I don't recall Do-Carmo introduced the notation $\left| \cdot \right|$ anywhere but I would assume it should be interpreted as

$$
\sqrt{\left\langle \frac{d \gamma}{dt} , \frac{d \gamma}{dt} \right\rangle}_{\gamma(t)} = \left| \frac{d \gamma}{dt}\right|
$$

Where $\left\langle \cdot, \cdot \right\rangle_p$ Is the Riemannian metric defined on the manifold $M$, am I right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you are right. This is standard notation for the Euclidean length of a vector.

Comment: Sorry I think I miss-understood your answer. The Riemmanian metric defines a euclidean space locally right? that means that the length of a vector is computed wrt that local metric, is it right?

Comment: Yes, it is right.